# Prevent Android App in background getting suspended

Tags: android

I wrote an App that will run process in a long time, possibly never ending until the user stop it.

But I afraid the App will get suspended when the mobile/tablet screen is sleep, or user switch to another app so that my app long running task is getting suspended.

How do I prevent that?

Comment: Forget to mention the long running task is running in a thread.

Comment: If you are long task is in an Activity then it will stop when user leaves Activity. You have to implement a Service and move your long task there.

Comment: Even a `Service` may be stopped or killed, but it's more likely to survive than an `Activity`.  For the highest priority, make it a [foreground service](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+foreground+service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably start a `Service` here if you want your Application to run in Background. This is what Service in Android are used for - running in background and doing longtime operations.

You can use `START_STICKY` to make your Service running continuously.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
handleCommand(intent);
// We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
// stopped, so return sticky.
return START_STICKY;
}
```

and see this :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle

and This is an example of background service:
http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html

Comment: Hi zheek, is the long running code be put in commented area in your code above?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is implement a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

It will have that behavior that you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Service` and return `START_STICKY` on the `onStartCommand()` so that the system will not terminate your app. Even if it is terminated, the service is automatically restarted.